# Invalid read of size 4 when separating thread

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, valgrind

I'm helping my friend to optimize his memory for this program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include "myutils.h"
#include <pthread.h>

void * mySPMDMain(void *);
pthread_barrier_t mybarrier;

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    /* Initialize global data here */
    /* Start threads*/

    int i;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./psrs <Number of Keys> <Number of threads>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct timeval start;
    struct timeval end;

    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    int NUM_THREADS = atoi(argv[2]);
    int allChunkSize = N/NUM_THREADS;
    pthread_t ThreadID[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_barrier_init(&mybarrier, NULL, NUM_THREADS);

    long int * originArray = (long int *) malloc(sizeof(long int)*N);

    for (i = 0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        originArray[i] = random() % 100000;
    }

    /*Initialize the Data Space*/
    TCB *myTCB = (TCB *) malloc(sizeof(TCB) *NUM_THREADS); 
    for (i = 0; i<NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        myTCB[i].Chunk = (long int*) malloc(sizeof(long int)*allChunkSize);
        myTCB[i].passLength = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_THREADS);
        myTCB[i].samples = (long int*) malloc(sizeof(long int)*NUM_THREADS);
        myTCB[i].tmpMergeSpace = (long int**) malloc(sizeof(long int *)*NUM_THREADS);
        myTCB[i].pivotArray = (long int *) malloc(sizeof(long int)*NUM_THREADS*NUM_THREADS);
        myTCB[i].selectedPivot = (long int*) malloc(sizeof(long int)*(NUM_THREADS-1));
        myTCB[i].eachStartIndex = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_THREADS);
        myTCB[i].mergeLength = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_THREADS);
        myTCB[i].sampleIndex = calloc((NUM_THREADS-1), sizeof(int));
        memcpy(myTCB[i].Chunk, &originArray[i*allChunkSize],allChunkSize*sizeof(long int));
        myTCB[i].N = N;
        myTCB[i].num_threads = NUM_THREADS;
        myTCB[i].ChunkSize = allChunkSize;
        myTCB[i].offSet = N/(NUM_THREADS * NUM_THREADS);
    }

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    for (i = 1; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        myTCB[i].pid = i; 
        pthread_create(&(ThreadID[i]),NULL, mySPMDMain, (void*) &(myTCB[i]));
    }
    myTCB[0].pid = 0;
    mySPMDMain((void *) &(myTCB[0]));

    for (i = 1; i<NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(ThreadID[i], NULL);
    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    double time_spent = (double)(end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1.0e6 + (double) (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
    time_spent = time_spent /1000000;
    //printf("time spent: %f\n", time_spent);

    memset(originArray, 0, N*sizeof(long int));
    int cursor = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(&originArray[cursor], myTCB[i].resultArr, sumTotal(myTCB[i].mergeLength, NUM_THREADS) * sizeof(long int));
        cursor = cursor+sumTotal(myTCB[i].mergeLength, NUM_THREADS);
    }
    /* Clean up and exit*/
    pthread_barrier_destroy(&mybarrier);
    assert(isSorted(originArray,N) == 1);
    for (i = 0; i<NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        free(myTCB[i].mergeLength);
        free(myTCB[i].eachStartIndex);
        free(myTCB[i].sampleIndex);
        free(myTCB[i].selectedPivot);
        free(myTCB[i].pivotArray);
        free(myTCB[i].samples);
        free(myTCB[i].passLength);
        free(myTCB[i].Chunk);
        free(myTCB[i].resultArr);
        for(int j = 0; j< NUM_THREADS; j++)
        {
            free(myTCB[i].tmpMergeSpace[j]);
        }
        free(myTCB[i].tmpMergeSpace);
    }
    free(myTCB);
    free(originArray);
    return 0;
}

#define MASTER if(localId == 0)
#define BARRIER pthread_barrier_wait(&mybarrier)

void * mySPMDMain(void *arg)
{
    TCB * localTCB;
    int localId;

    /* Actual parameter */
    localTCB = (TCB *)arg;

    /* Other parameters passed in via global */
    localId = localTCB -> pid;

    /* Parallel array to TCB */
    qsort(localTCB -> Chunk, localTCB -> ChunkSize, sizeof(long int), cmpfunc);
    BARRIER;

    // Timing

    /* Phase 1 */
    for (int i = 0; i< localTCB -> num_threads; ++i)
    {
        long int sample = localTCB->Chunk[i*localTCB -> offSet];
        localTCB->samples[i]=sample;
    }
    BARRIER;


    /* Phase 2 */
    MASTER {
        for (int i = 0; i < localTCB -> num_threads; ++i)
        {
            memcpy(&(localTCB->pivotArray[i*localTCB -> num_threads]),localTCB[i].samples, localTCB -> num_threads*sizeof(long int));
        }
        qsort(localTCB -> pivotArray, localTCB -> num_threads*localTCB -> num_threads, sizeof(long int), cmpfunc);
        for (int i = 0; i<(localTCB -> num_threads)-1; ++i)
        {   
            localTCB-> selectedPivot[i] = localTCB-> pivotArray[(i+1)*localTCB -> num_threads];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i<localTCB -> num_threads; ++i)
        {
            memcpy(localTCB[i].selectedPivot,localTCB[0].selectedPivot,((localTCB -> num_threads)-1)*sizeof(long int));
        }
    }
    BARRIER;


    /* Phase 3 */
    for (int i = 0; i<(localTCB -> num_threads)-1; ++i)
    {
        localTCB -> sampleIndex[i] = binarySearch(localTCB->Chunk,0,localTCB->ChunkSize -1, localTCB->selectedPivot[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<localTCB -> num_threads; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 0) localTCB -> eachStartIndex[i] = 0;
        else localTCB -> eachStartIndex[i] = localTCB -> sampleIndex[i-1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<localTCB -> num_threads; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0) localTCB -> passLength[i] = localTCB -> sampleIndex[i];
        localTCB -> passLength[i] = localTCB -> sampleIndex[i] - localTCB -> sampleIndex[i-1];
        if (i == (localTCB -> num_threads)-1) localTCB -> passLength[i] = localTCB -> ChunkSize - localTCB -> sampleIndex[i-1];
    }
    BARRIER;


    /* Phase 4 */
    MASTER {
        for (int i = 0; i<localTCB -> num_threads; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<localTCB -> num_threads; ++j)
            {
                // each temp merge space  = localTCB[i].tmpMergeSpace[j]
                // each cpy start = localTCB[j].Chunk[localTCB[j].eachStartIndex[i]]
                // each cpy length = localTCB[j].passLength[i] * sizeof(long int)
                localTCB[i].tmpMergeSpace[j] = (long int*) malloc(sizeof(long int)*localTCB[j].passLength[i]);
                localTCB[i].mergeLength[j] = localTCB[j].passLength[i];
                memcpy(localTCB[i].tmpMergeSpace[j], &(localTCB[j].Chunk[localTCB[j].eachStartIndex[i]]), (localTCB[j].passLength[i]) * sizeof(long int));
            }
            localTCB[i].resultArr = (long int *) malloc(sizeof(long int)*sumTotal(localTCB[i].mergeLength, localTCB -> num_threads));
        }
    }
    BARRIER;
    multimerge(localTCB->tmpMergeSpace,localTCB->mergeLength,localTCB -> num_threads,localTCB->resultArr);
    BARRIER;
    //Timing


    return NULL;

} /* mySPMDMain*/
```

and the TCB struct is this:

```
typedef struct ThreadControlBlock {
    long int *Chunk;
    int *passLength;
    int *sampleIndex;
    int *eachStartIndex;
    long int **tmpMergeSpace;
    long int *pivotArray;
    long int *selectedPivot;
    long int *samples;
    int *mergeLength;
    long int * resultArr;
    int pid;
    int N;
    int num_threads;
    int ChunkSize;
    int offSet;
} TCB;
```

I used `valgrind` to check if there's any memory leak. `valgrind` returns that this program freed memory after execution but has a invalid read of size 4 when executing thread function on the main thread (with `pid==0`):

```
==6150== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6150== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6150== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6150== Command: ./psrs 8000000 8
==6150== 
==6150== Thread 8:
==6150== Invalid read of size 4
==6150==    at 0x400DC2: mySPMDMain (psrs.c:169)
==6150==    by 0x4E3ADC4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==6150==    by 0x514673C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==6150==  Address 0x911cd5c is 4 bytes before a block of size 28 alloc'd
==6150==    at 0x4C29975: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==6150==    by 0x401188: main (psrs.c:48)
==6150== 
==6150== Invalid read of size 4
==6150==    at 0x400DBE: mySPMDMain (psrs.c:169)
==6150==    by 0x4E3ADC4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==6150==    by 0x514673C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==6150==  Address 0x911cd7c is 0 bytes after a block of size 28 alloc'd
==6150==    at 0x4C29975: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==6150==    by 0x401188: main (psrs.c:48)
==6150== 
==6150== Thread 1:
==6150== Invalid read of size 4
==6150==    at 0x400DC2: mySPMDMain (psrs.c:169)
==6150==    by 0x401266: main (psrs.c:64)
==6150==  Address 0x911a89c is 4 bytes before a block of size 28 alloc'd
==6150==    at 0x4C29975: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==6150==    by 0x401188: main (psrs.c:48)
==6150== 
==6150== Invalid read of size 4
==6150==    at 0x400DBE: mySPMDMain (psrs.c:169)
==6150==    by 0x401266: main (psrs.c:64)
==6150==  Address 0x911a8bc is 0 bytes after a block of size 28 alloc'd
==6150==    at 0x4C29975: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==6150==    by 0x401188: main (psrs.c:48)
==6150== 
==6150== 
==6150== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6150==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6150==   total heap usage: 174 allocs, 174 frees, 320,014,664 bytes allocated
==6150== 
==6150== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6150== 
==6150== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6150== ERROR SUMMARY: 16 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

line 169: `localTCB -> passLength[i] = localTCB -> sampleIndex[i] - localTCB -> sampleIndex[i-1];`

line 63: `myTCB[0].pid = 0;`

line 48: `myTCB[i].sampleIndex = calloc((NUM_THREADS-1), sizeof(int));`

In this test run, `NUM_THREADS` is `8`. If read correctly, `myTCB[i].sampleIndex = calloc((NUM_THREADS-1), sizeof(int));` should read a memory of 4 * (8-1) = 28 bytes, I don't quite get where should this 4 bytes invalid read before this 28 bytes block.

Comment: Which is line 169 in your `mySPMDMain()` function?  Valgrind is sure that you're accessing before and after the array of `NUM_THREADS-1` elements, so identifying that line may allow us to help you.  We shouldn't have to copy your code to find out which line it is.  Besides, you might have edited something.  Have you really reduced this to an MCVE ([MCVE])?  There's not a line of code in what you've shown that can be removed without removing the problem?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added the line

Comment: the posted code includes a home grown header file: `myutils.h`  Without the contents of that file, how are we to reproduce the problem?

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc): 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned type just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: `int allChunkSize = N/NUM_THREADS;` is an `int` divide.  So any fraction will be discarded.  This means the total 'allChunkSize *NUM_THREADS` has a VERY high probability of being too small.  Strongly suggest rounding the result up by `N` so AT LEAST the needed amount of memory will be allocated via this line: `myTCB[i].Chunk = (long int*) malloc(sizeof(long int)*allChunkSize);`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>` for `fprintf()`, etc   The posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` for `calloc()`, `malloc()`, and `free()`, exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

Comment: the returned value from `pthread_create()` needs to be checked to assure the thread creation was successful

Comment: the function: `sumTotal()` is not defined within the scope of the posted code. the function: `multimerge()` not defined within the scope of the posted code.  The function: `binarySearch()` not defined within the scope of the posted code.  The function: `cmpfunc()` not defined within the scope of the posted code.  The function: `isSorted()` not defined within the scope of the posted code.

Comment: this line: `myTCB[i].offSet = N/(NUM_THREADS * NUM_THREADS);` is a integer divide, so there is a very high probability that the field 'offSet' will contain a very small (perhaps even 0) value,  Probably not what you want.

Comment: @user3629249 you can assume that the headers and functions are included and defined in `myutil.h`

Comment: @user3629249 The answer to this question is correct. Since `N` is very large number (at least 80 million when I test), and `NUM_THREADS` is limited by machine settings. (at most 16 if tested locally on my machine) I should never worry about the issue that you are pointing.

Comment: C style note: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly indeed and should not have spaces on either side.  This is for human readability and following normal conventions, not because the compiler cares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line 169 is inside a for loop iterating with `i` from 0 up, but you are accessing element `sampleIndex[i-1]`. In the first iteration, this access is out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, I should set a condition for that too. I think why the program still works is the invalid reading of the memory is also `0`.

Answer (score 1):

@Honza is correct, take a look at these lines:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<localTCB->num_threads; ++i)
 {
     if (i == 0) localTCB->passLength[i] = localTCB->sampleIndex[i];
     localTCB->passLength[i] = localTCB->sampleIndex[i] - localTCB->sampleIndex[i-1];
     if (i == (localTCB->num_threads)-1) localTCB->passLength[i] = localTCB->ChunkSize - localTCB->sampleIndex[i-1];
 }
```

The branching here is not safe. when `i == 0`, for sure it will execute the line under `if (i ==0)` condition. BUT this loop will always execute the middle line! Then `localTCB->sampleIndex[i-1]` will read the `int` from `localTCB->sampleIndex[-1]` which is the int byte before the entire `sampleIndex` memory. Since this byte is also `0` (not used or populated), the result of the program is still correct, but obviously the "wrong way" for correct result. `valgrind` is strict and it will complain. And when `i == (localTCB->num_threads)-1`, the middle line will get the wrong value (`0`) too, but the final result will be corrected by the last condition. It means the branching is neither correct and efficient. How to change it? Simple, regulate each of the condition should be fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i<localTCB->num_threads; ++i)
{
    if (i == 0) localTCB->passLength[i] = localTCB->sampleIndex[i];
    else if (i > 0 && i<(localTCB->num_threads)-1) localTCB->passLength[i] = localTCB->sampleIndex[i] - localTCB->sampleIndex[i-1];
    else if (i == (localTCB->num_threads)-1) localTCB->passLength[i] = localTCB->ChunkSize - localTCB->sampleIndex[i-1];
}
```